# Is there a way to install Tensorflow 1.14.0 and opencv-4.4.0 for python 3.7 in Raspberry Pi 4 64 bit Debian 11?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, arm64, raspberry-pi4

I have tried installing it using the following link for pywheels: [Tensorflow bins](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa0dwOTE2OFdqTVJuU0xSZ3UtX00zeTBtVEl1d3xBQ3Jtc0ttVG9sMnQ3bUhfazNGTkZ1R0VXcGpCcERIWE01V3lzR1dvNjlRM3EtSGx3cHJRel9Tc080QmVveWl0a0EycEd1TjF4Tk9uQXlNbEVqdzh5T2NFcFc4Mm5hZ1hUb1h3LVczUlJ2QkRQQkhhOENKR2VBUQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FPINTO0309%2FTensorflow-bin%2Ftree%2Fmain%2Fprevious_versions&v=vekblEk6UPc).
The steps that i took to install tensorflow 1.14.0: Note: global python on Debian 11 is 3.9.2

1. Created a virtual enviroment and changed the local python version to 3.7.6 using pyenv in my local folder called 'project'.
2. Installed following dependencies:

   sudo apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev libc-ares-dev libeigen3-dev gcc gfortran libgfortran5 libatlas3-base libatlas-base-dev libopenblas-dev libopenblas-base libblas-dev liblapack-dev cython3 libatlas-base-dev openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev python3-dev build-essential cmake pkg-config libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libpng-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcairo2-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-103 libqt5gui5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5test5 python3-pyqt5
3. Downloaded pywheel: download_tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.sh
4. Installing the pywheel using chmod command gave the following error:
   [image]

I already tried to install Tensorflow it on 32bit OS for Pi4B and was successfull but when i wanted to import tensorflow to test it, it gave the following error: h5py versions dont match!->[image]

Regarding opencv, again i couldn't find how i can install a certain version in pi4. I could only install the latest using: `pip install opencv-contrib-python` ==4.4.0.44 wouldn't work.
I really ran out of ideas after trying for about 2 days. I would be very thankful for any small bit of help from the community:)

Comment: pip3install not  pip install

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to install it in a virtual environment. Try installing python 3.7.6 and follow the same steps you did.

I don't think you can choose the version of OpenCV on raspberry pi. It is mostly backward compatible so you don't need to worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try installing python 3.7.6 directly on global and then follow the steps. Regarding the OpenCV, I think I installed different versions on my mac but for pi 4B I haven't seen anyone do it. I hope its really backwards compatible.

Comment: @SherlockHomies - *Generally*, the reason we choose not to install OCV or TF on the RPi is the limited available resources.  RPis are amazing for some things, but certainly not at processing large datasets, nor running potentially complex models. *Especially* on immature Debian 11.

Comment: Thanks, i know that but i wanted to first give it a go with tensorflow and then with tensorflowLite. I would use tensorboard with Rpi 4 if needed in the end or go with jetson nano.